# Querying single relationship from a bidirectional relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, bidirectional-relation

[image: Overlapping bidirectional relationship]

Is it possible to show only one direction relationship from a bidirectional relationship?

(n)-[:EMAIL_LINK]->(m)

(n)<-[:EMAIL_LINK]-(m)

Comment: No in the browser you can't. However if you upgrade to 2.2M04, the browser shows them in a better way with curved edges.

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the redundant relationship between two nodes in cyper result set? 
I mean just hide or not to show in the result set.
`14 --> 41 ,
41 --> 14 ,
62 --> 41 ,
62 --> 14`
As you can see the node(14) is directly related to node(41), same with node(41) which is directly related node(14).

All I want to show is the unique node relationship in any directions.
`14 --> 41 , 
62 --> 41 ,
62 --> 14`
or 
`41 --> 14 ,
62 --> 41 ,
62 --> 14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relationship type in question does not have directional semantics, it's best practice to have them only one time in the graph and omit the direction while querying, i.e. `(a)-[:EMAIL_LINK]-(b)` instead of `(a)-[:EMAIL_LINK]->(b)`.

To get rid of duplicated relationships in different directions, use:

```
MATCH (a)-[r1:EMAIL_LINK]->(b)<-[r2:EMAIL_LINK]-(a)
WHERE ID(a)<ID(b)
DELETE r2
```

if your graph is large you need to take care of having reasonable transaction sizes by adding a `LIMIT` and running the query multiple times until all have been processed.

NB: the `WHERE ID(a)<ID(b)` is necessary. Otherwise `a` and `b` might change roles during in a later iteration. Consequently `r1` and `r2` would change roles as well and both get deleted.